# Prove $\theta:S\to E^G$ is $R$-module isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, homology-cohomology, group-homomorphism, module-isomorphism

I'm currently studying the paper *Galois Theory and Galois Cohomology of Commutative Rings* by S.U. Chase, D.K. Harrison and Alex Rosenberg. I'm trying to understand step by step the proof of Theorem 1.3, and there's a detail in (d)$\implies$(e) that I don't understand. Since there are useless context in the proof where I don't have issues with, I'll try to formulate a more general question that will solve my specific problem while being easier to understand:

> Let $S$ be a commutative ring, $G$ a finite group of automorphisms of
> $S$, and $R=S^G$ (subring of $S$ whose elements are left fixed by
> every element of $G$). Let $E$ be the $S$-algebra of all functions
> from $G$ to $S$ under pointwise addition and multiplication.
>
> Let $G$ act on $E$ by setting, being $\sigma,\tau\in G$, $s\in S$,
> $v\in E$:  $$(\sigma v)(\tau)=\sigma(v(\sigma^{-1}\tau)).$$ Now, $E^G$
> (elements of $E$ left fixed by every element of $G$) is easily seen to
> be the $G$-homomorphisms of $G$ to $S$ and thus the map $\theta:S\to
>  E^G$ defined by $\theta(s)(\sigma)=\sigma(s)$ is an $R$-module isomorphism.

I've succesfully understood that $E^G$ is made of the $G$-homomorphisms from $G$ to $S$. My question is about the proof if $\theta$ being $R$-module isomorphism. I think understand it's $R$-module homomorphism (due to the fact that $R=\{r\in S \mid \sigma(r)=r, \forall\sigma\in G\}$). However, I am unable to prove it's an isomorphism. I managed to prove it's injection, but can't do the same surjectivity. How can I prove it's a surjection?

Any help or hint will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, your 'more useful' way holds for all $\sigma$, so it is the same as $\sigma(v(\tau))=v(\sigma\tau)$ for all $\sigma$, which means $G$-homomorphism, provided that $G$ acts on itself by multiplication (and not conjugation). And moreover, it is just *equivalent* to the original condition $v\in E^G$.

Comment: @Berci thanks for your comment, I edited those details. But my question is, why $\sigma( v (\tau)) = v(\sigma\tau)$ means $G$-homomorphism? I understand one implication, but not the other one.

Comment: What do you think a $G$-homomorphism is?

Comment: @CaptainLama I now understand it. I was having trouble because I misunderstood $G$-homomorphism's definition. Now I'm struggling with proving $\theta$ is an isomorphism, I'm currently editing muy question to fit more to my real problem. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: The title of your post does not match the question you later ask in the body. You should edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\sigma \in G$, so it is an automorphism of $S$. This means that $\sigma$ is invertible (for composition). Injectivity is then easy to prove.

Let consider $f \in E^G$. To show surjectivity we need to find $ s\in S$ such that $\theta (s) = f$. Since $f : G \rightarrow S$ consider $s = f(1)$ where $1 \in G$ is the identity element.

Then

$$ \theta(s)(\sigma) = \sigma(s) = \sigma(f(1)) = \sigma(f(\sigma^{-1}\sigma)) = (\sigma\cdot_G f) (\sigma)=f(\sigma)$$

where $\cdot_G$ denotes the action of $G$ on $E$. The above equations hold for all $\sigma \in G$ so we have $\theta(s) = f$.